# Load PHP file in AJAX on site load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an php file that retrieves the newest 100 images from an directory. I have a script to automatically reload the php file, so that we can use the data with javascript.

But the problem is, we don't receive the information on site load, but only after 2 times the reload of the php file. We need the data on site load for other fuctions.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var array = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    window.setInterval(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update.php',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    array = result;
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
        var index;
        var text = "<ul>";
        for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            text += "<li>" + array[index] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }, 5000);

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file array export:

```
echo json_encode($files);
```

Comment: woo please fix your indentations this is too hard to read.

Comment: Thanks, but that line is eventually not needed. The problem is i need the data on site load, but the data comes in after 2 reloads of the update.php

Comment: Could you please define to me what you believe "site load" means. because the data IS available when the page is loaded. It is not global because you forgot to assign it to the `array` array but it is there trust me. Please research JavaScript Scoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [];
function displayArray(array) {
  var text = "<ul>";
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    text += "<li>" + array[index] + "</li>";
  text += "</ul>";
  $("#demo").html(text);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  array = <? php echo json_encode($files); ?> ;
  displayArray(array);
  window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'update.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(x){
        array = x;
        displayArray(array);
      },
      dataType: "json"
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

**EDIT**: I made the array global for you which I think is what you are mistaking for "load".

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, i need the data on site load, for other purposes. the display array loop is only for testing

Comment: so then just move that line that loads the initial array out of the document ready statement, it will become global, which i think is what you are asking for because in this script it IS loaded with the site.

Answer (score 1):

use callback function as in the code snippet below.
this will execute the code below the ajax request only after the response has been received.

The problem here is because the ajax request is asynchronous. This runs in the background and the code after the ajax request runs first.

```js
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'update.php',
cache: false,
success: function(result) {
    callbackFunction(result)
},
dataType:"json"
});  

function callbackFunction(array) {
    var index;
    var text = "<ul>";
    for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      text += "<li>" + array[index] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever use async false, always write non-blocking code, take advantage of the ``success`` callback to execute any code that requires the ajax return before execution. Your code could severely slow down the browser depending on how much data is being transferred via ajax.

Comment: I've updated the code above. Thankyou @Dustin Poissant for poiniting out